# Jmeter: Creates multiple records for single user

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter. Please help me.
I am trying to automate a scenario which will login to application with my username and password and then logout.
My web application does not use session id for logins. It just uses username/password/unique cookie every time.

I recorded this script and put in test plan. On executing it, Jmeter creates hundreds of records in DB with same user name and timestamp.

How do I avoid this happening. Please help.

Comment: Can someone please help

Comment: Can some one please help. Struggling with this. Not sure how to make it work. Completely blocked on this case. I do not have any loop created and number of thread is only 1 and rampup perios is 1. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probable have set multiple thread users.

Under **Thread Group** change

- **Number of Threads (users)** to 1.
- **Ramp-Up Period (in seconds)** to 1.
- **Loop Count** to 1

Comment: No I have set only to 1. Number of Threads (users) to 1.
Ramp-Up Period (in seconds) to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send different user name and timestamp each time so use:

1. [random string](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) for user name for example `${__RandomString(10,abcdefg)}`
2. [${__time()}](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) for timestamp